# writing a program to run another written program

Tags: c++

I'll start with my use case. I am a teacher and I have students writing pretty simple c++ console programs for me. I want to automate grading their programs by writing a test harness for their whole application. When they use cin to ask for input I want to give it. When they use cout I want to be able to parse their output for correct functionality. I'm pretty sure my teachers did this for us when I was in college. What is a good way to go about this? Is there a better way to validate their code than parsing output? Should I parse their actually code and look for function declarations? Thanks.

Comment: bash would be probably easiest way. If you insist on C/C++ then first you want to pipe filedescriptors so you can provide data to their 0 (in) and 1 (out) filedescriptors by own functions.

Comment: Please don't grade them exclusively on the results of this automated procedure.

Comment: It's your job and professional duty, so be so kind to to do this yourself :)

Comment: Those are the standard requirements for test suite, so any test suite framework (like e.g. DejaGnu) should work. Of course in case of a failure you'll still have to look at *why* it failed (it would be a pity to not pass a test because the student e.g. mistyped "total" as "tootal" in the output text). So basically it saves you the work of checking those entries which work, and otherwise just helps you to identify the parts of the code you'll have to inspect manually.

Comment: How many programs are we talking here?  Also, comments based on code quality and readability are just as important as correct functionality in the real world.  Direct feedback on their identifier names would be very useful to newer students that don't understand that variables and functions like a(),b,c,ff,gj,etc. a good program doesn't make.

Comment: so you know enough c++ to teach, but not enough to do a program like this? hm... OK, nobody knows anything, but I'd expect a teacher to come up with some ideas and look for guidance with specific problems.

Comment: Remember to think about security!  Some sneaky student might try `system("rm -rf ~/*")`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise you not to invent the wheel and use something like [SPOJ Engine](http://www.sphere-research.com/en/), [see also](http://www.spoj.com/info/) which already has all necessary features as: secure sandboxing, providing faked user input and so on.

By the way, I just recalled [one more thing for automatic submission testing](https://github.com/edx/xserver)

Answer (score 0):

You question is fairly open, but one thing you might want to look into is the C++ system command. See more info about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to be doing this on a POSIX-y OS like Linux or MacOS/X, forkpty() will do this pretty easily... see the example below which runs a "ping 127.0.0.1" in a child process and prints out the ping process's stdout output as it read()'s it.  You could write to the child process's stdin using write() on the same file descriptor.

A similar technique is also possible under Windows, but as per tradition it's about 10 times more difficult and awkward there.  Let me know if that's something you need to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#if defined(__linux__)
# include <pty.h>     // for forkpty() on Linux
#else
# include <util.h>    // for forkpty() on MacOS/X
#endif

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   int fd;
   pid_t pid = forkpty(&fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   if (pid > 0)
   {
      // We're running in the parent process.  We can now write to the child process
      // (and read from it) via (fd).
      while(1)
      {
         char buf[4096];
         int numBytesRead = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
         if (numBytesRead > 0)
         {
            buf[numBytesRead] = '\0';  // ensure termination
            printf("Read from child process's stdout: [%s]\n", buf);
         }
         else if (numBytesRead == 0)
         {
            printf("Child process exited\n");
            break;
         }
         else {perror("read"); break;}
      }
   }
   else if (pid == 0)
   {
      // We're running in the child process.

      // Turn off the echo, we don't want to see that back on stdout
      struct termios tios;
      if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tios) >= 0)
      {
         tios.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL);
         tios.c_oflag &= ~(ONLCR); /* also turn off NL to CR/NL mapping on output */
         (void) tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tios);
      }

      char * const argv[] = {"/sbin/ping", "-c", "5", "127.0.0.1", NULL};  // Replace /sbin/ping with your favorite program to run instead
      if (execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0) perror("execvp");
   }
   else if (pid < 0) perror("forkpty");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use for unit testing. Write some headers, write unit tests for the function the headers define, then give the headers and unit tests to the students and refuse to grade their work until the tests pass. To further reduce any wasting of your time, make them compile everything with `-Wall -Werror`.

Once the tests do pass, I'd look through the code to make sure they're not doing anything evil just to make the tests pass.

The best unit testing framework I've seen for C++ is [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/). It's easy to write and easy to run.

On the other hand, if all you care about is input and output, just use bash and pipes:

```
#!/bin/bash

for executable in * ; do
    if cat input.txt | $executable | diff - expected-output.txt > /dev/null ; then
        echo $executable passes
    else
        echo $executable fails
    fi
done
```